# Boolean expressions in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query like:

```
select 
  (a=1 and b=0 and k>n) test1
from math_table
where j != i 
order by (a=1 and b=0 and k>n) desc
```

and surprisingly this returns 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0 kind of result.
but if I use `order by test1 desc` it works: 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0

I did some research about boolean expressions on MySQL ORDER BY clause but nothing I found that can explain that odd behavior.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Please post sample data (CREATE TABLE.. and INSERT.. statements), which can reproduce that issue. Also post your server version.

Comment: You should follow  @PaulSpiegel suggestion,Topicstarter this can help you with that [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  to provide example data and expected results..

Comment: Topicstarter you have to remember that SQL language is declarative in nature, in a `select` where you define *"what you want to have"* and not  *"how to get it"*.. The *"how to get"* part you defined as a table structure  in short that means that table structure(s) and or data in some cases for that matter can change the meaning of a SQL statement..  With other words without knowing table structure we can only give a **educated guess** what a query might do